# Can't compile a programm from git: serial problem STM32L476

Tags: c++

i'm trying to compile a programm from git, working on Mbed cli, stm32L476RG and an accelorometer X3, i want to create a data logging, this is all commands output:

```
mbed compile -t GCC_ARM -m nucleo_l476rg --source neai_vibration_tutorial\neai_vibration --source mbed-os
'Serial' does not name a type Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
```

Comment: Going to guess you are missing header files for your project that define this Serial type.  You have given so little information that we can't help much more than this.

Comment: i just clone the project from github, i found somewhere that the serial sould be defined in mbed.h wich exist

Comment: But that header is not included, the command line to your compiler doesn't know about it, or you have failed to install other things needed to make this work.  Take a close look at the requirements for building this product (hopefully on the git info page) and see if you need more still on your local system.  Sometimes it requires running a file to setup ENV variables so that the compiler can find stuff as well.